# "Тонус", "Тонизировать"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Близки ли понятия "тонизировать" и "гармонизировать" или "успокаивать, оказывать седативное воздействие". Если человек слишком напряжен, всклочен, и он выпивает чашечку чая, это его приводит в "порядок", "состояние меньшего нервного напряжения". Вообще тонус - это здоровое, обыкновенное, не отклоняющееся в сторону возбуждения или торможения состояние, верно?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, тонус - это степень жизнедеятельности. Он может быть повышенный, пониженный. Тонизировать - взбодрить, сделать тонус более напряжённым.

http://tolkslovar.ru/t3476.html

Какой-то отдельный орган человека "в тонусе" означает, что он напряжён, нужны как раз седативные средства, успокаивающие. Если говорят: "Он всегда в тонусе", значит, он всегда бодр и подвижен. Тонизирующие напитки - бодрящие. Чай как раз не успокаивает, а бодрит (впрочем, как для кого, кто-то от него засыпает, а кто-то не может уснуть, смотря какой ещё чай). Предлагают попить чаю для успокоения обычно не из-за чая, а для того, чтобы отвлечь человека, переключить внимание на другую, спокойную обстановку.

А вот гармонизировать - как раз делать спокойным в меру